# Use htaccess to redirect subdomain to a directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had a subdomain setup with an A record, this subdomain is now no longer active, and is pointing to the root of the hosting account.

How can I create a htaccess redirect to direct the subdomain,  shop.domain.com to domain.com/shop

As the subdomain now points to domain.com, if I use the following redirect it obviously doesn't work:

```
Redirect 301 "/"  http://www.domain.com/shop/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/shop/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` checks to make sure that the hostname of the request begins with the string "shop." and if so, the subsequent `RewriteRule` is evaluated.

The `^` before `shop` ensures that it only matches the string "shop" if it is at the beginning of the hostname.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that does the trick. Do you mind explaining the RewriteCond line, is that a wildcard search for the term 'shop' in the URL, or is it specific to the fact 'shop' is a subdomain?